# Where I can find the body of triggerd event in MarionetteJS

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am new to MarionetteJs I have code in my project

```
_onClick: function(event){
this.trigger('selected');
 }
```

Where I can find the body of this event , I want to go the definition to this event , please help

Comment: Anything else that has access to `this` can setup a listener for it. Search your project for "selected" maybe?

Comment: I have searched in whole project couldn't find it @TJ .

Comment: It can be something like `onChildViewSelected` or `onMyPrefixSelected`. You'll have to go through them carefully. "where is x in my project" is not really answerable without the project or an [mcve]...

Comment: Well I found it in parent file its like `childview:selected` , Can you explain what is `:` for , and thanks for ur time @TJ

Comment: `childview` is defaut event prefix for marionette item views, see [child event prefix docs](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/events.html#a-child-views-event-prefix).

`:` is a naming convention for events, marionette maps them to methods in camel case according to this [docs](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/events.html#onevent-binding)

Comment: In other words, since this event is triggered from a child view, marionette appends `childview` prefix to it according to naming convention, hence the propogated event becomes `childview:selected`, which bubbles to it's parent collection view and will automatically trigger an `onChildviewSelected` method on it, if there is any. It is also possible to catch these events on collection view using `childEvents` hash or by manually adding listeners

Comment: got it @TJ thanks for ur great time :)